# C++ How to dispatch to different template function by tag

Tags: c++, templates, switch-statement

There's lots of template functions called f1,f2,f3…

How to dispatch an runtime-known int to different template functions?

Of course I can use switch to do that, but every time I add more template functions or delete some template functions, I have to modify the switch again and again. How can I do that in a more elegant way?

Templates are not real-exsited functions so that I can't make a std::map of functions pointers.

```
template<typename T> std::optional<T> f1(){...}

template<typename T> std::optional<T> f2(){...}

template<typename T> std::optional<T> f3(){...}

template<typename T> std::optional<T> f4(){...}

template<typename T> auto dispatch(int tag){

    switch(i){
    case 1: return f1<T>();
    case 2: return f2<T>();
    case 3: return f3<T>();
    case 4: return f4<T>();
    }// I have to modify these if add or delete some template functions

}
```

Comment: Please show some code

Answer (score 0):

Here is the explanation for [command pattern](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/38412-the-command-pattern-c/), i guess its what you are looking for.

There are no templated functions, so i rewrote it. Its not doing what it was its purpose (convert numbers) but you can choose which function you want to call and its templated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <bitset>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>
#include <cctype>

template <typename T>
class converter
{
public:
    virtual std::string convert(T) = 0;
    virtual ~converter() {}
};

template <typename T>
class hex_converter : public converter<T>
{
public:
    std::string convert(T i)
    {
        return "H: " + i;
    }
};

template <typename T>
class oct_converter : public converter<T>
{
public:
    std::string convert(T i)
    {
        return  "O: " + i;
    }
};

template <typename T>
class bin_converter : public converter<T>
{
public:
    std::string convert(T i)
    {
        return "B: " + i;
    }

};


class dictionary
{
    std::map<char, converter<std::string>*> dict;

public:
    dictionary()
    {
        dict.insert( std::make_pair( 'B', new bin_converter<std::string> ) );
        dict.insert( std::make_pair( 'O', new oct_converter<std::string> ) );
        dict.insert( std::make_pair( 'H', new hex_converter<std::string> ) );
    }

    converter<std::string>* lookup(char x)
    {
        std::map<char, converter<std::string>*>::const_iterator iter;
        iter = dict.find( toupper(x) );

        if( iter != dict.end() )
            return iter->second;
        else
            return NULL;
    }

    ~dictionary()
    {
        while( dict.begin() != dict.end() )
        {
            delete dict.begin()->second;
            dict.erase( dict.begin() );
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    char ch = 'h';
    string output = "";
    dictionary dict;

    converter<std::string>* con = dict.lookup( ch );

    if( con != NULL )
        output = con->convert( "Test" );
    else
        output = "Invalid";

    cout << "Result: " << output;
}
```

Comment: Not the anwser I'm looking for at all. You dispatch char to functions(although initialised from template), I want to dispatch int to different templates. Templates are not real-exsited functions so I can't make a std::map of functions pointers. What I want is a little bit like double-dispatch, but dispatch by int AND the type parameter of template. I can do that by switch, but it doesn't fit for the situation when I often add or delete templates, because I'd have to add or delete the corresponding case of switch .